# exclude rows which contain all 0's

Tags: r, matrix

I would like to exclude the rows in a data frame which contain all 0's.

I can check for if a row contain 0 or not by using %in% operator. But need to know how to iterate over an entire matrix. and then print the new matrix excluding the other rows.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What have you tried?  Can you post a snippet or two of the code you have written so far?   What does your data look like?  Post some of it using `dput(head(yourdata))`.  Right now it sounds like you want us to write your code for you!  But, a hint in the right direction: take a look at the functions `?all` and `?any`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using Senor O's sample data (`DF <- data.frame(A=rep(c(1,0),5), B=0)`), try:

```
DF[!rowSums(DF == 0) == ncol(DF), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
AllZeros = apply(DF, 1, function(X) all(X==0))
DF2 = DF[!AllZeros,]
```

Try it with:

```
DF <- data.frame(A=rep(c(1,0),5), B=0)
```

As sample data.

Comment: Shorter and faster would be `AnyNonZero = apply(DF != 0, 1, any)`, then `DF[AnyNonZero, ]`. Yet, despite the short-circuiting, I'm sure @Ananda's solution will still be much faster unless the number of columns becomes very large.

Answer (score 1):

There are a ton of ways to do this as the guys who have answered so far will show you.

I'll provide one more example off of this example dataset created.

```
    DF <- data.frame(A=rep(c(1,0),5), B=0)
```

The `subset` command works well.

```
    newDF <- subset(DF, !(A == 0 & B == 0) )
```

Depending on the size of your matrix and the naming convention of your variables, this may be tedious in which case I'd go straight for the apply functions.